# I am trying to take a single input from user but somehow the computer asks for two inputs?

Tags: c++, c, input

```
 void coordinateInput(int in){
     int * input = (int *)malloc(in*(sizeof(int)));
     for (int i = 0; i < in; i++){
         printf("Please enter the x coordinate for control point #%d: ", i); 
         scanf("%d\n",&input[i]);
         printf("Please enter the y coordinate for control point #%d: ", i); 
         scanf("%d\n",&input[i+1]);
     }
 }
```

In output you can see after line 0 it asks for another input:
[image: Screenshot of output]

I want the to get only one input but I end up having the input twice for some reason. Its only true for first case only.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, *Complete*, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with caller code (maybe the `main()` function).

Comment: Newline character after `%d` in `scanf()` makes it wait for next non-space character and it may lead to unexpected behavior. (waiting for MCVE before posting an answer)

Comment: @DigitalHero C **or** C++? Choose one first. BTW, the posted code is wrong. It doesn't make sense. You allocate memory for `in` `int`s but try to store `2 * in` `int`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it removing '\n' from the scanf statement and adding it in the printf.

```
int * input = (int *)malloc(in*(sizeof(int)));
 for (int i = 0; i < in; i++){
 printf("Please enter the x coordinate for control point #%d: ", i); 
 scanf("%d",&input[i]);

 printf("\nPlease enter the y coordinate for control point #%d: ", i); 
 scanf("%d",&input[i+1]);
 //[In output you can see after line 0 it asks for another input][1]}
 printf("%d - %d\n", input[i], input[i+1]);
}
```

The code should be something like that.